# Defining Ninject's binding without scope to keep the code DRY

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a *Web* project and a *Windows Service* project in my solution. I have created 2 different binding modules for these 2 projects, but as you can see it has a lot of duplicate code... the only difference is that I am using `InRequestScope()` for the *Web* project and `InTransientScope()` for *Windows Service* project.

Is it possible combine the bindings, and add the scope depending on the project/entry point?

```
public class WebModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>().InRequestScope();
        // more types ... InRequetScope();
    }
}

public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();
        Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>().InTransientScope();
        // more types ... InTransientScope();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

As explained by [ninject team](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/issues/372), we can use `InRequestScope()` in both scenarios... since there is no concept of Request in a Windows Service project, ninject would use the default scope, which is `InTransientScope()` in the service project.

---

### Original Answer

The best solution that I have come up with is to create an extension method:

```
public static class NinjectExtensions
{
    public static IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> GetScopeByName<T>(this IBindingInSyntax<T> syntax, string scope)
    {
        if (scope.Equals("request", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return syntax.InRequestScope();
        }
        else if (scope.Equals("thread", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return syntax.InThreadScope();
        }
        else if (scope.Equals("singleton", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return syntax.InSingletonScope();
        }
        
        return syntax.InTransientScope();
    }
}
```

And set the scope dynamically.

```
public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    private string _scope = "transient";

    public MyModule()
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsWebProject"]))
        {
            _scope = "request";
        }
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().GetScopeByName(_scope);
        Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>().GetScopeByName(_scope);
        // more types ... InRequetScope();
    }
}
```

*Note: I am not sure if there is a better solution... this is just the cleanest approach that has come to my mind.*